# Floating button over native WiFi settings

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to invoke the native WiFi settings screen from my app. The android navigation bar is disable to fully control the flow from the app. Hence, when the native settings screen is displayed there is no way to come back to the app. My idea es to place a floating button but the cases I saw are based on custom activities and I have no a clear vision about how to get the result I illustrated with this pic.

[image]

Comment: What you're suggesting would require an additional permission for your app to draw over other apps, which would have a whole other set of navigation issues for you. My question would be, what action are you asking the user to take, and why do they need to be on this screen? Is there a different way of handling whatever you're asking the user to do?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie since there is no android navigation bar neither hardware buttons, all the navigation is controlled from the app. When the settings screen is shown there is no way to back to the application. This is the reason why I need an extra visual control to return.

Comment: I followed a different approach that solves my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013528/specify-an-activity-back-from-native-wifi-settings-screen/47016050#47016050