# Specify an activity back from native WiFi settings screen

Tags: android

In my particular case, the application is intended to be running in an embedded system where the application flow is handled by the app itself and the android navigation bar is disabled (no hardware buttons either).

At some point, I have to provide the settings of the WiFi to connect and I wanted to invoke the native settings screens. However, I found in troubles to come back to my app after the settings are done.

I realized there is a software button enabled in the title bar ***only*** when you arrive to that screen from the parent settings menu. Is there any chance to specify the activity back from my app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call Wi-Fi setting from your app using this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true)
        .putExtra("extra_prefs_set_back_text", "Back to the app!")
        .putExtra("extra_prefs_set_next_text", ""));
```

Comment: Working like a charm in KitKat and Marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

In my use case I was able to get the top-left arrow to finish the settings activity and thus return to my app by adding the following override to the SettingsActivity.java file in packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/SettingsActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

and then rebuilding the AOSP source